# ListView Popup Message

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to dynamically generate messages based on which item is clicked in a ListView. I have tried the code that I posted below. I want this to give a message of text that relates to the item clicked.

```
int messageId = getResources().getIdentifier(item,"strings",getPackageName());
                        String popUpMessage = getString(messageId);
                        PopUp.setMessage(popUpMessage);
                        PopUp.show();
```

Comment: you can show message value by its position in listview

Answer (score 0):

By this code how will you know which item is clicked?

use itemclick listener for the listview, then you will get which item is clicked.

Use the int position parameter to get which item is clicked.

Comment: I have this inside the onitemclick listener. to get the name of the string i use `String item = (String) drinkList
         .getItemAtPosition(position);` but when i click on something it crashes. I can get the title to be set as the item that is clicked but i cant get the custom message to be set
         .getItemAtPosition(position)`

Answer (score -1):

The following steps are needed

1. Get a ListView

   ```
   ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
   ```
2. Register a listener on the items.

   ```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {


   }

   });
   ```
3. Make an alert dialog for it(paste it inside the onclick method above).

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
   builder.setMessage(item);
   builder.show();
   ```

## update for the comments

For the dynamic message you just need to set the message property of the builder.
Like this -

`builder.setMessage((String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));`

The above line assumes that your listView consists of only one thing if it has multiple things like a row containing a title and a message and you want to retrieve the message and set it to the dialog. Then do this

```
View rowView=(View)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
TextView messageView=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);
builder.setMessage(messageView.getText().toString());
```

i hope that answers it.

Comment: Is there a way that i could get the string item from a resource like strings.xml instead of the ListView. as i would want the title of the AlertDialog to be the item at the position but the message something that is related to that item.

Comment: ya use this method setTitle(int titleId) pass in your string id like builder.setTitle(R.string.something);

Comment: right but is there a way to dynamically get that id?

Comment: By dynamically you want to change the title?

Comment: use getString(((View)parent.getItemAtPosition()).getId()); try this.

Comment: dynamically change the message. sorry for the delay i was at class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46798/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-arachnid-hivemind)

Comment: builder.show() doesn't show anything it has to be attached to a AlertDialog to be shown:

`AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();`



`// show it`


`alertDialog.show();`

Comment: @AliNfr , show calls create first. Here's a reference for it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create()